# Query to return records between business years not working correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have found myself in problems querying for records beween business years.
In this case, business year always starts on `01/08/YYYY` and end on `31/07/YYYY`.
For example:
For `2019-2020` business start: `01/08/2019` ends `31/07/2020`
For `2020-2021` business start: `01/08/2020` ends `31/07/2021`

When I opened the database today, records still show up even though it is a new business year.
Its as though my queries do not work from the beginning of a new Business year. I have:

```
'To return records for the Current Business year:
SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[PaymentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1))) Between -6 And 5));

'To return records for Previous Business year: 
SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE (((DateDiff('m',[PaymentDate],DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,1,1))) Between -6 And 5));
```

My question is, how do I correctly query records for the Current business year and Previous business year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the previous business year:

```
select t.*
from tblData t
where year(dateadd('m', -8, PaymentDate)) = year(date()) - 1
```

The logic is to subtract 8 months from the date and then extract the year.

Comment: I must be missing something here but: `year(datediff('m', -8, PaymentDate))` gives 1903 for all dates

Comment: You probably mean `DateAdd` instead of `DateDiff`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff `01/08/2020` has to appear in the current business year. Therefore `Year(DateAdd('m', -7, PaymentDate)) = Year(Date()) - 1` ?

Comment: @Fil . . . I think that is the logic.  It is a little unclear on which year is the "current" business year, so there might be an off-by-one confusion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In this case the current business year started on `01/08/2020` therefore it will run until `31/07/2021`. I  think this clears the confusion? I have suggested and edit to your answer so that I may mark as complete?

Answer (score 1):

If the start and end of business year is constant (`yyyy/08/01` - `yyyy+1/07/31`) then try this - for the current year:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tblData As t
WHERE t.PaymentDate BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()), 8, 1) AND DateSerial(Year(Date())+1, 7, 31);
```

for previous year:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tblData As t
WHERE t.PaymentDate BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date())-1, 8, 1) AND DateSerial(Year(Date()), 7, 31);
```

If you would like to pass year value to the query, try this:

```
--pass year to the query to grab data for business year yyyy/08/01 - yyyy+1/07-31

PARAMETERS BusinessYear SHORT;

SELECT t.*
FROM tblData As t
WHERE t.PaymentDate BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(BusinessYear), 8, 1) AND DateSerial(Year(BusinessYear)+1, 7, 31);
```

For further details, please see: [PARAMETERS declaration (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-declaration-microsoft-access-sql)